# Getting an accurate count of Pageviews per Session

Tags: google-analytics, page-views

Is there a way in Google Analytics to see the complete profile of Pageviews per session on your site. (How many sessions had 1, how many had 2 etc) I'm currently only able to see Avg Pageviews per session.

Currently this 3.4 but I wonder how accurate this is. We have a 40% bounce rate so does that not mean that 40% of the sessions have only 1 Pageview but then the rest must have much more than 3.4 on average?

I would like to be able to find out, besides the people who bounce immediately, how many pages does a user visit in a session.

Comment: What do you mean by "sessions had 1, sessions had 2"?

Comment: Sessions which had only 1 pageview and sessions which had 2 pageviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stats what you looking for is available at **Audience** > **Behavior** > **Engagement** on the tab **Page Depth**

[image]